# Python recursive function returns none type even after using the return to the function?

Tags: python, function, return, return-value

I am working on this code segment:

```
result=[]
def function(i,x,Tree,result):
    if isinstance(Tree,ExNode):     
        return 0    
    a=Tree.tempatt
    if x[a]<Tree.tempval:            
        return result.append(Tree.val), function(i,x,Tree.left,result)
    else:                   
        return result.append(Tree.val), function(i,x,Tree.right,result)
```

Here, tempatt, tempval, val are the components of the Tree class.

This function works as desired but return **None**. However, in the variable explorer I can see the result variable with the desired values forming a list.

Comment: `append` returns None.

Comment: Yes thanks, I checked that but what else structure to use to get all those values returning from the recursive loop? Any suggestions?

Comment: You could return `result + [Tree.val]` if you want to return a combined list. Or you could append to `result` and then return `result`.

Comment: instead of 'return' lines write this : 'result.append(Tree.val), function(i,x,Tree.left,result)'  and then 'return result'

Comment: result + [Tree.val]... return a tuple of list. But its fine, i can convert that into a list.   Thanks a lot @khelwood

Comment: @sadafShafi: thanks a lot. I understand my mistake....Your approach is much better

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Write it like this

```
result=[]
def function(i,x,Tree,result):
    if isinstance(Tree,ExNode):     
        return 0    
    a=Tree.tempatt
    if x[a]<Tree.tempval:  
        result.append(Tree.val), function(i,x,Tree.left,result)  
        return result
    else:
        result.append(Tree.val), function(i,x,Tree.right,result)          
        return result
```

In your case you weren't returning a list , but a function which returns none